# FOSUserBundle: using event listener to save related registration data

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, user-registration, event-listener

I've just updated to the latest version of FOSUserBundle that does away with FormHandlers.

Each User in my app has a "Home" and I am using the registration form to capture info about the Home when the user create's their account.

Originally I had overridden the FormHandler to save the extra data using the onSuccess method:

```php
public function onSuccess(UserInterface $user, $confirmation)
{
    $home = $user->getHome();
    $this->documentManager->persist($home);
    $this->documentManager->flush();

    parent::onSuccess($user, $confirmation);
}
```

this successfully saved the Home document and the reference to it in the User document.

With the event listener approach that you have to use now, I've subscribed a listener on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` and created the following method:

```php
public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $home = $user->getHome();

    $this->documentManager->persist($home);
    $this->documentManager->flush();

    $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
}
```

This saves the Home, but doesn't save the reference in User. As I'm using the `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` event, the User has already been saved by the RegistrationController, whereas before the Home was saved first, so that may have something to do with it?

However, I assumed re-saving the User after the Home was created would be enough?

If I `var_dump($home)` after the flush, then it has the correct value for the id property.

If I call `$user->setHome($home)` after the flush, the reference in User is still NULL.

I haven't changed my underlying model since the update, it's still using the same Doctrine Mongo ODM classes, so the reference should still save?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the FormHandler way and the `REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` EventListener way seemed to be that in the former, the User was not saved until after the Home had been created.

So, I've changed my listener subscription to the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` event which fires before the User is saved:

```php
public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
    $home = $user->getHome();
    $this->documentManager->persist($home);
    $this->documentManager->flush();
}
```

This successfully saves the Home reference in User, although it does make me worry a bit that I couldn't seem to update the Home reference once the User is saved?